# WCF OData for multiplatform development?

Tags: wcf, architecture, orm, odata

The OP in this question asks about using an WCF/OData as an internal data access layer.

[Arguments of using WCF/OData as access layer instead of EF/L2S/nHibernate directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498796/arguments-of-using-wcf-odata-as-access-layer-instead-of-ef-l2s-nhibernate-direct)

The resounding reply seems to be don't do it.  I'm in similar position to the OP, but have a concern not raised in the original question.  I'm trying to develop (natively) for a lot of different platforms but want to keep as much of the data and business logic server side as possible.  So I'll have iOS/Android/Web (MVC)/Desktop applications.  Currently, I have a single WinForms applications with an ORM data access layer (LLBLGen Pro).

I'm envisioning moving most of my business / data access logic (possibly still with LLBLGen or other ORM) behind a WCF / OData interface.  Then making all my different clients on the different platforms very thin (basically UI and WCF calls).

Is this also overengineered?  Am I missing a simpler solution?

Comment: I should add that I finally opted to use ServiceStack.NET for this project.  I was strongly influenced by Matt Cowan's excellent LLBLGen template library for generating ServiceStack.NET: http://www.mattjcowan.com/funcoding/2013/03/10/rest-api-with-llblgen-and-servicestack/  And also concerns about OData performance, flexibility, and scalability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see any problem in your architecture or consider it overengeenered as a OData is a standard protocol and your concept conforms the DRY principle as well.

I change the question: Why would you implement the same business logic in each client to introduce more possible bugs and loose the possibility to fix the errors at one single and centralized place. Your idea makes you able to implement the security layer only once.

OData is a cross-platform standard and you can find a OData libraries for each development platform ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee720179), [OData.org](http://www.odata.org/), [JayData for JavaScript](http://jaydata.org)). Furthermore, you can use OData FunctionImports/Service methods and entity-level methods, which will simplify your queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running multiplatform development, then you may find more practical to choose platform-agnostic communication protocol, such as HTTP, rather than bringing multiple drivers and ORMs to access your data Sources directly. In addition since OData is a REST protocol, you don't need much on the Client side: anything that can format OData HTTP requests and parse HTTP responses. There are however a few aspects to be aware of:

1. OData server is not a replacement for an SQL database. It supports batches but they are not the same as DB transactions (although in many cases can be used to model transactional operations). It supports parent-child relations but it does not support JOINs in classic SQL sense. So you have to plan what you expose as OData entity. It's too easy to build an OData server using WCF Data Services wrapping EF model. Too easy because People often expose low Level database content instead of building high level domain types.
2. As for today an OData multiplatorm clients are still under development, but they are coming. If I may suggest something I am personally working on, have a look at Simple.Data OData adapter (https://github.com/simplefx/Simple.OData, look at its Wiki pages for examples) - it has a NuGet package. While this a Client Library that only supports .NET 4.0, part of it is being extracted to be published as a portable class Library Simple.OData.Client to support .NET 4.x, Windows Store, Silverlight 5, Windows Phone 8, Android and iOS. In fact, if you check winrt branch of the Git repository, you will find a multiplatform PCL already, it's just not published on NuGet yet.

Comment: Vagif--thanks for response.  I may be unclear--I certainly don't intend for the OData layer to replace my SQL data store but to create a server side middle tier that communicates with the various native clients via OData and accesses the data layer via an ORM.  (I actually need to support several different databases, which is part of the reason for the ORM).  Your point regarding (1) is definitely something I'll consider. A lot of my app is just CRUD so I'll admit being tempted to expose DB entities more or less directly. I'm also  looking closely at http://www.servicestack.net/ right now.